# Why do I keep getting this error message

Tags: error

Why do I keep getting the error message below after I attempt to save the data I inputted into CiviCRM?

Sorry but we are not able to provide this at the moment. DB Error: unknown error Return to home page. Fatal error: Uncaught CRM Core_Exception: [0: Transaction integrity error: Expected to find active frame thrown in /var/www/sites/all/modules/civicrm/Civi/Core/Transaction/Manager.php on line 107

Comment: it might help to provide more context on how/where this data is being entered

Comment: Also, please include messages from the logfile at the time of the error.